# Provide default value for optional field in Django model

Tags: python, django

I have written a Python model as given below:

from django.db import models

```
class Product(models.Model):


        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

        def sell(self):

                self.quantity = self.quantity - 1
                self.save()
                return self.quantity
```

When I am trying to create the schema using migrate, I get the following message:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'description' to product without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

My question is, if I am setting 'blank=True' for 'description', is it necessary to specify a default value for the field? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3):

`blank=True` is not the same as `null=True`, as [the documentation explains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#blank). When a text field is blank, it still needs some kind of value: but that value can be the empty string.

So, just select option 1, and enter `''` as the default value.

Comment: OK, I see. 'blank=True' is only for the field, while 'null=True' is for both the field and the database entry. Yes, the schema got created, thanks for clearing my doubts!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a ticket created for this behavior for Django 1.7.
Take a look [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23405)

Comment: ohh...but I need to use that schema somewhere else..:(

Comment: For now you can just enter the default '' by hand, when that bug is fixed it will just do that automatically, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `default=""`.

Comment: This anwer may be suitable to OP, you should also add some explanation or link to docs. See how do I write a good answer [answer].